# FinBox.com logging in with UrlFetchApp to access another link?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-400, urlfetch

I can't log in successfully from Google Apps Script despite looking for solutions hours long, including many entries in SoF.

The login process sends a POST request to this url: https://finbox.com/_/api/v5/tokens

Input of the credentials happens here: https://finbox.com/login/email

Response code is 400.

Any help will be really appreciated :)

So far I ended up with this:

````
function testFinBoxWithCredentials(stock = "AAPL") {

 var options = {
   method: 'post',
   contentType: 'application/json',             
   payload: {
     email: 'xxxxxxxxx',
     password: 'xxxxxxxxx'
   },
   muteHttpExceptions: true,
   followRedirects: false 
 };

 const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://finbox.com/_/api/v5/tokens", options);
 
 Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
 if ( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
   Logger.log("Couldn't login.");
 }
 else if ( response.getResponseCode() == 302 ) {
    Logger.log("Logged in successfully");

    var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];     
    Logger.log(cookie);

    //Access then a link like https://finbox.com/NASDAQGS:AAPL
    /* var cookies = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];     
       for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
          cookies[i] = cookies[i].split( ';' )[0];  
       };
       
       url2 = "https://finbox.com/NASDAQGS:AAPL";
       options2 = {
           "method": "get",
           "headers": {
              "Cookie": cookies.join(';') 
           }
       }

       var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options2);
       var content = response2.getContentText(); 
       Logger.log(content)*/
} ```
````

Comment: Can you provide the detailed specification of the API you want to use? Can you provide the official document of the API?

Comment: Is it json? Try sending as formurlencoded

Comment: @Tanaike I think there's no documentation. OP wants to recreate the requests sent by his browser, when he logs in manually.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. From the URL of `https://finbox.com/_/api/v5/tokens`, I thought that the official document might be existing. I'm worried that when the official document is not existing, it might be difficult to test the script.